# BCS: how to pass input parameter in GetList operation in ECT?

Tags: external-content-type

Sorry for this basic question, but I am new to SharePoint and programming in general.

I have a wcf web service which contains the following CRUD operation:

```
GetFilteredCompanies(string country); // this shows a list of all the companies based on the filter
```

After I have created an external content type in SharePoint designer and I go to see the list created, it is empty because `GetFilteredCompanies` expects a value.

Where can I enter this value/argument so that the list can be filtered? is there a way to provide this argument afer the external content type is created?

I need to create different external content types for different subsites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding the ReadList operation you can specify a Filter. Select the Data Source Element and then click Filter link. Once the filter is setup you can use that to pass the parameter.

For that open the External List in browser. Then say modify view. Then put the Filter Value.

Comment: @BurreIfort nice to hear that.